# Android L Bluetooth Low energy DeviceDiscovered event

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My use case is to scan for BLE devices every 1 second.

I have created a Timer and scheduled it for every 1000 in which i call "StartScan" function of "BluetoothLeScanner" class.

Trouble is that it discovers device in multiples of 5 like after 5 seconds or 10 seconds sometimes 20 seconds as well even though i keep the phone at the same place.

Android documentation is of no help in this.

I have tested my sample app with Nexus 4 and Moto G both running  on stock android L

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Comment - have you tried scanning other devices? Maybe it is a problem with the device you are scanning.